# Error opening librarian file when trying integration in Perforce

Tags: integration, perforce

Today I was trying to integrate from a child `streamC` to a parent `streamP` (copy-up operation) in Perforce. This operation is performed almost every day and usually we don't experience any issues. But today something went wrong. On a few files Perforce throws an error:

```
Operation 'rmt-FileFetch' failed.
Librarian checkout /opt/perforce/..../fileA
Error opening librarian file /opt/perforce/..../fileA revision 1.2555519.
RCS checkout 1.2555519 failed!
RCS no such revision 1.2555519!
```

And the same error is shown on a few other files.

I've checked status of these files in a parent stream `streamP` and they are all marked for delete by somebody else.

Is it a bug in perforce that you cannot integrate file deletion if it is already marked for delete?

Or is it a perforce infrastructure issue and I need to talk to IT guys?

Comment: You may need help from Perforce Technical Support. The fact that the message says 'rmt-FileFetch' indicates that you've got something more complex going on (remote depots? replica or edge servers?) If the files are opened for delete, perhaps one of your administrators is already trying to address the damaged files somehow?

Comment: Files that are already marked as "integrated" in a pending changelist can block subsequent attempts at integrating the file.
Perforce can come back with "Error - all revision(s) already integrated" but omits the context that the "integration" that another user performed hasn't actually been submitted yet.  In the worst-case scenario the user has left the pending integration in their default changelist.
You can try:
p4 opened -a //...depotfile/... and perforce should respond with the location of the file, if it is pending, and so forth.  This can rule out one of the nodes in the toolchain

Answer (score 2):

If the file is deleted in the source there shouldn't be a librarian operation at all.  Sounds a lot like this (fixed) bug:

```
Bugs fixed in 2016.1

    #1378013 (Bug #85458) **
        'p4 copy' could produce a librarian error when attempting to copy
        a source file that was moved and then deleted.  Fixed.
```

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/relnotes.txt